# Calculator having single square bracket button along with 1..9 button

Tags: button, calculator, square-bracket

I am creating a calculator with design similar to image shown below. I dig into internet to get the logic for bracket button () , but fails to get the answer .

[image]

Comment: Rule 1: After an operator or an opening bracket, the `()` button behaves as an opening bracket. Rule 2: After a digit, a dot or a closing bracket, the `()` button behaves as a closing bracket.

Answer (score 0):

Say the calculator has `54` displayed and you have pressed `+`. Next you enter `4` and then `*` and finally enter `2`. That will result in the calculator displaying `116` since it operates on parameters as they are entered.

If you instead entered `54`, `+`, `()`, `4`, `*`, `2`, `()` it would output `62` since the parenthesis told it what order to evaluate in.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @Guvante. But this doesnt solve my querry. I need a logic for single square button logic, just like we have logic for multiple key i.e *